# Splitting a sentence into words using for loop or while loop in java

Tags: java, reverse

i have to do a program which takes a sentence and reverses it word by word in java. for eg:
India is my country

output:aidnI si ym yrtnuoc

ive figured out all of it but i just cant split a sentence into separate words.im not allowed to use split function but im meant to use either substring or indexof();while loop and for loop are allowed.
this is what ive got so far:

import java.io.*;

public class Rereprogram10

{

```
public void d()throws IOException

{

 BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

 String str;

 System.out.println("input a string");


 str=br.readLine();

 String rev="";
 int length=str.length();
 int counter=length;
 for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
 {
     rev=rev+str.charAt(counter-1);
     counter--;
    }
    System.out.println("the result is: "+rev);
}
```

}

its wrong though,the output keeps on coming:
yrtnuoc ym si aidnI
i havent learnt arrays yet...

Comment: Post your code snippet

Comment: wouldn't reversing 'India is my country' "word by word" make it come out to 'country my is India'?

Comment: he meant post your snippet in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that advanced datastructures are out, and efficiency is not an issue.

Where you are going wrong is that you are reversing the entire string, you need to only reverse the words.  So you really need to check to find where a word ends, then either reverse it then, or be reversing it as you go along.

Here is an example of reversing as you go along.

```
int length=str.length();
String sentence="";
String word = "";
for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) != ' '){
        word = str.charAt(i) + word;
    } else {
        sentence += word +" ";
        word = "";
    }
}
sentence += word;
System.out.println("the result is: "+sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

This passes the test:

```
package com.sandbox;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class SandboxTest {

    @Test
    public void testQuestionInput() {
        String input = "India is my country";

        assertEquals("country my is India", reverseWords(input));
    }

    private String reverseWords(String input) {
        List<String> words = putWordsInList(input);

        Collections.reverse(words);

        return Joiner.on(" ").join(words);
    }

    private List<String> putWordsInList(String input) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        String word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (c == ' ') {
                words.add(word);
                word = "";
            } else {
                word += c;
            }
        }
        words.add(word);
        return words;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code without split() for you.

Input:
India is my country

Output:

country my is India

aidnI si ym yrtnuoc

You can choose the output you need.

```
public class Reverse {
    public static class Stack {
    private Node[] slot = new Node[1000];
    private int pos = 0;
    private class Node{
        private char[] n = new char[30];
        private int pos = 0;
        public void push(char c) {
            n[pos++] = c;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return new String(n).trim() + " "; // TODO Fix
        }
    }

    public void push(char c) {
        if(slot[pos] == null)
            slot[pos] = new Node();

        if(c != ' ') {
            slot[pos].push(c);
        } else {
            slot[pos++].push(c);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = pos; i >=0; i --)
            sb.append(slot[i]);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String reverseWord(String word) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int len = word.length();
        for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            sb.append(word.charAt(i));
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public String foryou() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < pos + 1; i ++)
            sb.append(this.reverseWord(slot[i].toString()));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    String sentence = "India is my country";
    System.out.println(sentence);
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i ++) {
        stack.push(sentence.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(stack);
    System.out.println(stack.foryou());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String x="India is my country";
StringBuilder b=new StringBuilder();


int i=0;
do{
     i=x.indexOf(" ", 0);
     String z;
     if(i>0){
         z=x.substring(0,i); 
     }
     else{
         z=x;
     }

     x=x.substring(i+1);
     StringBuilder v=new StringBuilder(z);
     b.append(v.reverse());
     if(i!=-1)
     b.append(" ");
     System.out.println(b.toString());

}
while(i!=-1);
```